# Not able to parse and get array results from json

Tags: java, json

I know how to parse json and get results from json array in java, but I have a json in which I am not able to find out which is an array, and how do I parse it, in this json I want 'state' and 'base_url'. can some one help me how do I do this.

```
{
    "tree": [{
        "data": {
            "title": "/clusterstate.json",
            "attr": {
                "href": "zookeeper?detail=true&path=%2Fclusterstate.json"
            }
        }
    }],
    "znode": {
        "data": "{\n  \"cmn2\":{\n    \"shards\":{\n      \"shard1\":{\n        \"range\":\"80000000-ffffffff\",\n        \"state\":\"active\",\n        \"replicas\":{\n          \"core_node1\":{\n            \"state\":\"active\",\n            \"base_url\":\"myurlforjson\",\n            \"core\":\"cmn2_shard1_replica1\",\n            \"node_name\":\"myurlforjson:8080_solr\"},\n          \"core_node3\":{\n            \"state\":\"active\",\n            \"base_url\":\"myurlforjson\",\n            \"core\":\"cmn2_shard1_replica1\",\n            \"node_name\":\"myurlforjson:8080_solr\",\n            \"leader\":\"true\"}}},\n      \"shard2\":{\n        \"range\":\"0-7fffffff\",\n        \"state\":\"active\",\n        \"replicas\":{\n          \"core_node2\":{\n            \"state\":\"active\",\n            \"base_url\":\"mydomainmyurlforjson:8080/solr\",\n            \"core\":\"cmn2_shard2_replica1\",\n            \"node_name\":\"myurlforjson:8080_solr\"},\n          \"core_node4\":{\n            \"state\":\"active\",\n            \"base_url\":\"myurlforjson\",\n            \"core\":\"cmn2_shard2_replica1\",\n            \"node_name\":\"myurlforjson:8080_solr\",\n            \"leader\":\"true\"}}}},\n    \"maxShardsPerNode\":\"1\",\n    \"router\":{\"name\":\"compositeId\"},\n    \"replicationFactor\":\"1\"},\n  \"elect\":{\n    \"shards\":{\n      \"shard1\":{\n        \"range\":\"80000000-ffffffff\",\n        \"state\":\"active\",\n        \"replicas\":{\n          \"core_node3\":{\n            \"state\":\"active\",\n            \"base_url\":\"myurlforjson\",\n            \"core\":\"elect_shard1_replica1\",\n            \"node_name\":\"myurlforjson:8080_solr\",\n            \"leader\":\"true\"},\n                                  \"core_node5\":{\n            \"state\":\"active\",\n            \"base_url\":\"mydomainmyurlforjson:8080/solr\",\n            \"core\":\"elect_shard1_replica1\",\n            \"node_name\":\"myurlforjson:8080_solr\"}}},\n      \"shard2\":{\n        \"range\":\"0-7fffffff\",\n        \"state\":\"active\",\n        \"replicas\":{\n          \"core_node4\":{\n            \"state\":\"active\",\n            \"base_url\":\"myurlforjson\",\n            \"core\":\"elect_shard2_replica1\",\n            \"node_name\":\"myurlforjson:8080_solr\"},\n          \"core_node6\":{\n \"state\":\"active\",\n            \"base_url\":\"myurlforjson\",\n            \"core\":\"elect_shard2_replica1\",\n            \"node_name\":\"myurlforjson:8080_solr\",\n            \"leader\":\"true\"}}}},\n    \"maxShardsPerNode\":\"1\",\n    \"router\":{\"name\":\"compositeId\"},\n    \"replicationFactor\":\"1\"}}",
        "prop": {
            "pzxid": 4294967540,
            "czxid": 4294967540,
            "mzxid": 12884915656,
            "mtime": "Thu Feb 20 09:00:48 UTC 2014 (1392886848018)",
            "ephemeralOwner": 0,
            "children_count": 0,
            "cversion": 0,
            "ctime": "Thu Dec 05 10:19:10 UTC 2013 (1386238750279)",
            "aversion": 0,
            "dataLength": 2388,
            "version": 1119
        },
        "path": "/clusterstate.json"
    }
}
```

This is my code, let me know where do I parse

```
URL url = new URL("http://myipaddress:8080/solr/zookeeper?  detail=true&path=%2Fclusterstate.json");

    System.out.println(url);

    java.net.URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    //String ref = "http://ajax.googleapis.com";
    //connection.addRequestProperty("Referer", ref);

    String line;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            connection.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(line);
    }

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(builder.toString());


    //System.out.println(json);
    JSONArray entries = json.getJSONArray("tree");
    for (int i = 0; i < entries.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject row = entries.getJSONObject(i);

        bean test   = new bean();
        test.setRss(row.getString("data"));
        System.out.println(row.getString("data"));

    }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    return "cloud";
}
```

Comment: have you tried using **json.parse(jsonresponse)**;

Comment: No, I will try and let you know, thanks for quick reply

Comment: Why is the value at pointer /znode/data a serialized JSON object and not the object itself?

Comment: First go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It takes 5-10 minutes.

Comment: But in the above, "state" and "base_url" are in the doubly-encoded JSON string at znode data.  You need to extract the "data" string and run it through the JSON decoder again.

Comment: (The above code is barking up the wrong "tree".)

Comment: @fge - That's what they do sometimes.  There are good reasons and bad reasons.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject znode = json.getJSONObject("znode");
String data = znode.getJSONObject("data");
JSONObject dataJson = new JSONObject(data);
```

From there you're on your own -- it looks like cmn2 ->shards -shard1 ->state, et al, but it's a bit hard to read the JSON in that form.  I suggest logging dataJson so you can see it more clearly.